# What should return when using CSRF tokens with class-based views?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.7, django-csrf

> Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. 
>   Request aborted. Reason given for failure: CSRF cookie not set.

I get the above error and there are a few solutions out there, but not for class-based views. What should `def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):` be returning? Below the message, it suggests 4 solutions, and the following suggestion catches my attention. So perhaps I should be returning a `RequestContext` somehow?

> The view function uses RequestContext for the template, instead of Context.

I'm already using `{% csrf_token %}`, cookies are enabled and I have it included in the middleware. So I think I may be returning the wrong thing but all the other examples around here use function views.

My template snippet:

```
{% if not user.is_authenticated %}

<form id="login" method="post" action="login">{% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login">
</form>

{% elif user.is_authenticated %}

<p>Welcome, {{ user.get_displayname }}.</p>

{% endif %}
```

My urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from mainapp.views import Index, LoginResponse
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
from mainapp import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', Index.as_view()),
    url(r'^login$', LoginResponse.as_view()),
)
```

My LoginResponse class view:

```
class LoginResponse(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(LoginResponse, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            return context
```

Comment: So what does LoginResponse look like?

Comment: I added the class view above

Comment: Well that view makes no sense. You don't define `request` anywhere, and you ignore the return value of `authenticate` - and you shouldn't be authenticating inside `get_context_data` anyway. Are you sure that is actually your code? If you did run it you would certainly get a NameError.

Comment: Actually, are you sure that is the view that is rendering that template in the first place?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, CSRF middleware intercepts request before hitting the view so it is why he didn't get a NameError.

Comment: I checked my Apache access log and it says it's HTTP 405.

Answer (score 0):

For CSRF verification there is no difference between function based and class based views.  This verification is done at middleware level.

So show your template and urls.py please.

Comment: Added template and urls.py to the original post

Comment: Hm, look fine for me.  Are sure that you pointing to valid view?  What happens then you comment out `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` from `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`?  And, just in case, show your view.

Comment: Can you try this view without `CsrfViewMiddleware`?

Comment: I removed it, and now after logging in, I'm taking to a plain white page located at `/login`, but I went back to the homepage and the django template language thinks I'm not logged in. I need to search my browser cookies maybe to confirm

Comment: Something wrong with you `urls.py`. Instead of empty white page you should get a standard django error page (your view is incorrect and raises NameError). Show us a whole urls.py.

Comment: Added my full `urls.py`

Comment: Very strange. Does your admin work fine? Can you create/update objects in `/admin/`? Does this error remain then you use `manage.py runserver` instead of apache deployment?

Comment: I think Python 2.6.6 is running when 2.7 should be. Looking into this now, will comment back when resolved the version mismatch